# Creating multiple dataframes in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to create 4 dataframes with different data from Xs and Y's. Please help me out in this.

Code:

```
# here we are creating 2d imbalanced data points 
ratios = [(100,2), (100, 20), (100, 40), (100, 80)]
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
item_iter=0
for j,i in enumerate(ratios):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, j+1)
    X_p=np.random.normal(0,0.05,size=(i[0],2))
    X_n=np.random.normal(0.13,0.02,size=(i[1],2))
    y_p=np.array([1]*i[0]).reshape(-1,1)
    y_n=np.array([0]*i[1]).reshape(-1,1)
    X=np.vstack((X_p,X_n))
    y=np.vstack((y_p,y_n))
    df[item_iter]=pd.DataFrame(X,y)
    item_iter+=1
    plt.scatter(X_p[:,0],X_p[:,1])
    plt.scatter(X_n[:,0],X_n[:,1],color='red')
plt.show()
```

For each of the ratios we get different X's and Y's and I want to capture it different datasets like df_1,df_2,df_3,df_4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them into a dictionary. Dictionaries can hold each type of python objects:

```
data_frames = {}
ratios = [(100,2), (100, 20), (100, 40), (100, 80)]
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
item_iter=0

for j,i in enumerate(ratios):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, j+1)
    X_p=np.random.normal(0,0.05,size=(i[0],2))
    X_n=np.random.normal(0.13,0.02,size=(i[1],2))
    y_p=np.array([1]*i[0]).reshape(-1,1)
    y_n=np.array([0]*i[1]).reshape(-1,1)
    X=np.vstack((X_p,X_n))
    y=np.vstack((y_p,y_n))
    data_frames[f"{i}_{j}"]=pd.DataFrame(X,y)
    item_iter+=1
    plt.scatter(X_p[:,0],X_p[:,1])
    plt.scatter(X_n[:,0],X_n[:,1],color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: But how do we access the dataframes. I am getting error when I try to access it.

Comment: Here I stored them as `{"100_2": df_1, "100_20": df_2}` . You can access the dataframe by calling the key: `data_frames["100_20"]`.